# OnLoad event in iframe not firing in IE8 after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an iframe on my page and I am trying to reload the contents.  In all other browsers this is achieved by simply doing:

```
$('#myFrame').contentWindow.location.reload(true)
```

However, this does not work in IE (tested in 9 and 8) and I found that I can get it to reload by cloning the iframes container, adding the clone to the page and removing the original iframe as shown below:

```
var pe = $(window.parent.frames['myFrame'].frameElement.parentElement);
clonedPe = pe.clone();
clonedPe.insertBefore(pe);
pe.remove();
```

The problem that I have is that on the original iframe I had some code added to the onload event but this is not fired on the load of the cloned iframe.

My question is....is there a better way of reloading the iframe in IE  -  OR  -  how can I get the onload event to fire on reload!?!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the source of the iframe it will reload:

```
var pe = $(window.parent.frames['myFrame'].frameElement.parentElement);
$.data(pe, 'src', pe.attr('src'));
pe.attr('src', 'about:blank').attr('src', $.data(pe, 'src'));
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZgKh/1/

You can also bind your events to the iframe using `.delegate()` so the event handler will hold true for any matching elements that are inserted into the DOM after the event handler is bound:

```
$(document).delegate('iframe', 'load', function () {...});
```

Note that in jQuery 1.7 and greater the perferred method is:

```
$(document).on('load', 'iframe', function () {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in FF and IE9.

```
$('#myFrame').get(0).contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: That works to refresh the frame but this is the same problem that I had before in the the load events don't re-fire.

Comment: So the iframe's HTML has a load event and while the HTML is refreshed the load doesn't fire? To be clear the load event is in the iFrame's source... could we see it?